# PHP SOAP body - need to set schema version

Tags: php, soap, schema, php-5.3, soap-client

I am using a non-wsdl soap call to a web service and I am able to build the request how I need however I need to set a schema Version within the envelope body.

I am able to build this request with the PHP SoapClient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.discovery.co.za/vitality">
<env:Body>
<ns1:UsageEligibilityRequest>
        <ns1:RequestingEntityNumber>12345678</ns1:RequestingEntityNumber>
         <ns1:Entities>
            <ns1:EntityNumber>12345678</ns1:EntityNumber>

            <ns1:DateOfBirth>1980-01-01</ns1:DateOfBirth>

            <ns1:Gender>M</ns1:Gender>
            <ns1:FirstInitial>H</ns1:FirstInitial>
         </ns1:Entities>
</ns1:UsageEligibilityRequest>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

However I need this line:

```
<ns1:UsageEligibilityRequest>
```

to be

```
<ns1:UsageEligibilityRequest schemaVersion="1.0">
```

Not sure how to do this in PHP using the built in functions/options and appears to be hard to Google.

This is built using code like:

```
$client->__soapCall('UsageEligibilityRequest', array($options));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways you can do this

```
$requestingUser = 12345678;
$entityNumber = 12345678;
$dateOfBirth = '1980-01-01';
$gender = 'M';
$firstInitial = 'H';
```

1. Either use a SoapVar like:

   ```
   $paramsSOAPVar = new SoapVar('<ns1:UsageEligibilityRequest schemaVersion="1">  
      <ns1:RequestingEntityNumber>' . $requestingUser. '</ns1:RequestingEntityNumber>  
         <ns1:Entities>  
            <ns1:EntityNumber>' . $entityNumber. '</ns1:EntityNumber>
            <ns1:DateOfBirth>' .$requestingUser. '</ns1:DateOfBirth>
            <ns1:Gender>' .$gender. 'M</ns1:Gender>
            <ns1:FirstInitial>' .$firstInitial. '</ns1:FirstInitial>
         </ns1:Entities>
      </ns1:UsageEligibilityRequest>', XSD_ANYXML);
   ```
2. Set up your array of parameters:

   ```
   $params = array(
      'schemaVersion' => 1,
      'RequestingEntityNumber' => $requestingUser, 
      'Entities' => array(
          'EntityNumber' => $entityNumber,
          'DateOfBirth' => $dateOfBirth,
          'Gender' => $gender,
          'FirstInitial' => $firstInitial
       ) 
   );
   ```